# Can we get local classes using reflection?

Tags: java

Is there a way to get Class X from Test.class

```
class Test {

    void test() {
        class X {
        }
    }
}
```

using reflection?

Comment: You need to understand how the Java compiler / JVM maps local class names to internal class names, then just call `Class.forName(...)` with the right internal class name.

Answer (score 2):

It's similar to how you'd do an inner class using `Class.forName`

```
class Test {
    class X {} // "Test$X"
}
```

Except it's prefaced by a number (much like an anonymous inner class) since there can be multiple local definitions

```
class Test {
    void test() {
        class X { // "Test$1X"
        }
    }
    void test2() {
        class X { // "Test$2X"
        }
        class Y { // "Test$1Y"
        }
        System.out.println(new X(){}) // "Test$1"
        System.out.println(new X(){}) // "Test$2"
        System.out.println(new Y(){}) // "Test$3"
    }
}
```

It would be interesting to know if the JLS guarantees the numbering based on the order of the code, but I wouldn't place any bets on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following idiom, assuming a self-contained example in a `Main` class:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class c = Class.forName("test.Main$Test$1Foo");
        // testing methods
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c.getDeclaredMethods()));
    }
    static class Test {
        void test() {
            class Foo {
                void bar(){}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
[void test.Main$Test$1Foo.bar()]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can identify these anonymous classes using reflection, by accessing the `classes` field on the `ClassLoader` object. This field appears to keep track of all the loaded classes. If you then check for classes where [`getCanonicalName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getCanonicalName()) return null, you will then be able to identify these classes. It is not very pretty, but it gets me class `X` in this case.

The only caveat is that this doesn't appear to work if class `X` is not referenced anywhere.

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String... args) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    class X {

    }

    ClassLoader classLoader = RiskWrapper.class.getClassLoader();

    System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager() {
      @Override
      public void checkPermission(Permission perm) {

      }
    });
    Field classes = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("classes");
    classes.setAccessible(true);
    Vector<Class<?>> loadedClasses = (Vector<Class<?>>)classes.get(classLoader);

    Class<X> xClass = X.class;

    for(Class<?> loadedClass : loadedClasses) {
      if(loadedClass.equals(xClass)) {
        System.out.println("Found anonymous class " + loadedClass.getName());

      }

    }

    System.out.println();

  }
}
```

Output:

Found anonymous class Main$1X